# How do I determine a Keypath for a given key and iterable?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an `Immutable.js Map` that looks something like this:

```
item1: {
  prop1: {
    potato: true,
    turnip: false,
    ragamuffin: true
  }
},
item2: {
  prop1: {
    petunia: true,
    azalea: false,
    stinkweed: true
  }
}
```

I am writing a function that'll take a `keyName` and `newValue`. Instead of enumerating each `keypath`, I'd like to be able to do something like:

`state = state.setIn(state.getKeyPath(keyName), newValue)`

For this project, duplicate key names are not a concern (i.e., no `Map` I parse will have >1 instance of any `keyName`)

ETA: my current solution is OK for now b/c my state will never be nested >1 level deep, but would rather use a built-in method if one exists:

```
let keyName = 'petunia'
let keyPath

// make a List of all top-level keys, then loop through each
List(sampleMap.keys()).forEach((topLevelKey) => {

  // if we find our key, assign our keyPath accordingly
  if (sampleMap.hasIn([topLevelKey, keyName]) === true) {
    keyPath = [topLevelKey, keyName]
  })
})
```

Comment: what will be your `keyName` from your sample map ?

Comment: hmm--let's say my `keyName = 'petunia'` and my `newValue = false`

Comment: AFAIK there is no built-in method to get the keyPath by keyName since keyName is not unique. the solution you using is good for 1 level deep maps otherwise you have to iterate through